# Need helpful error message from mod_proxy_fcgi

Tags: apache-2.2, php, apache-2.4

When a non-existent php script is requested, mod_proxy_fcgi provides a rather useless error message, basically just saying

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] .... AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
```

This server is using Apache 2.4.6 (Centos 7), with php handling configured as:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

I really would like to know the actual script name, because it may contain useful information (such as indicating a defective link, an error in a page name, or merely showing that it is just another fool hunting for a server with unprotected wp-login.php).

I tried changing LogLevel from info to debug, but then the error log was also filled with valid php script access details, which makes quite a mess of the error log, since those are not actually errors.

Is there some way to get a more useful proxy_fcgi error message which includes the actual script name for non-existent php scripts?

Comment: I can of course rummage through the access log, but the issue here is finding a way to get proxy_fcgi (or a suitable replacement module) to produce a useful error message in the error log (which is where it seems most appropriate for errors to be logged).

Answer (score 2):

You can define ErrorLogFormat including the %L
and then do the same in your CustomLog format %L

That will make Apache log a specific id which will bind an errorlog entry into the access log entry and then all you need to do is grep.

Example:

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%{u}t] [%-m:%l] [%L] [pid %P:tid %T] %7F: %E: [client\ %a] %M% ,\ referer\ %{Referer}i"

LogFormat "%h %l %u [%L] %t \"%r\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

So next time, when you see an error, you check the ID in it and grep the access.log for the same id

Answer (score 0):

I would get the time of the logged error and then search the access log around that time for requests that return a failure. That should help track down the script.

Answer (score 0):

The error in question is coming from the FastCGI application (whatever is listening on port 9000), not Apache.  Apache is simply reporting what comes back in the FastCGI `FCGI_STDERR` stream.

If Apache is talking to PHP-FPM (as seems likely), you can look at PHP-FPM's logs.  You can check the `error_log` directive in your `php-fpm.conf` file to find out where PHP-FPM is logging errors.  There should be more clues there.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to check if the file exists before passing it to the handler, which is what the default Debian [configuration file](https://salsa.debian.org/php-team/php/-/blob/debian/main/7.4/debian/php-fpm.conf#L17) suggests.

```xml
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

That way, if the file doesn't exist, Apache will handle it, instead of PHP.